# Is there any better way to find n! without just multiplying all the numbers till n?

Tags: sequences-and-series, factorial, factoring

I was solving some permutation, combination problems where we know that we are to use factorial. So I was thinking if there was any shorter way, maybe a formula, than multiplying all the numbers till $n$ to find $n$!

I know how to add series like $1+2+3+4+…+n$ which is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$ but I didn't find much on how to multiply. So... how to do it then?

Comment: It's $((n+x)!)/((n-1)!)$

Comment: ${n+x \choose n-1}(x+1)$ is also another one.

Comment: I do not think so. Any method will comprise of you multiplying something with something else.

Comment: I mean what if you are asked the answer of "194!" Is there any alternative way to fond out the ans without just multiplying from 1 to 194?

Comment: So there is no formula invented like n(n+1)/2 for this problem yet? that's odd

Comment: @Farhan there are nice approximations. However, if you want the exact answer, there no neat condensed form like there is for addition.

Comment: @Farhan one analog to the $n(n+1)/2$ is that you can simplify $b^nb^{n-1}\cdots b^1$

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html formula (8) gives a 'closed form' for the Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation).

Comment: $n!=\Gamma(n+1)$

Comment: [look at my answere here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/90911/calculating-the-factorial-of-a-number-efficiently/90941#90941)

Answer (score 0):

After your editing of the original question:

You will not find an easy formula for the **exact** evaluation of factorials, except using $n! = \Gamma(n+1)$. If you want to compute faster than just multiply the numbers, use e.g. the prime power table approch.

A basic fast algorithm is described in P.B. Borwein, On the complexity of calculating factorials, Journal of Algorithms, Vol.6, pp. 376-380, 1985. Available as http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/personal/pborwein/PAPERS/P29.pdf

Here the four steps of Borwein's algorithm for $n!$:

1. Construct the prime table $2 \le p_k \le n\;$ (e.g. using a [sieve method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes))
2. Compute the exponents of the $p_k$ in $n!\;$ (e.g. [Legendre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula))
3. Compute $O(\log n)$ numbers $\alpha_i$ (for details see the paper)
4. Compute $n! = \prod \alpha_i$

For actual implementations see e.g. the mentioned [FastFactorial Functions](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/FastFactorialFunctions.htm) page.